# MVVM Command Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am developing a WPF application using the MVVM pattern. I have a window with two controls: a user control and a button. The button's Command property is bound to a RelayCommand (from MVVM Light) on the user control's VM. Here is the xaml:

```
<local:TraceChartView x:Name="chartView"/>
<Button Content="Copy To Clipboard" 
        Command="{Binding ElementName=chartView, 
                          Path=DataContext.CopyToClipboardCommand}"/>
```

So clicking the "Copy To Clipboard" button executes the CopyToClipboardCommand RelayCommand in the TraceChartView's VM. This works fine, but it requires me to use a complicated mechanism to get the command from the VM to the TraceChartView's code behind where it can actually implement the action. It seems like I should be able to implement something like a dependency property in the TraceChartView's code behind and bind the button action directly to it, i.e.:

```
<local:TraceChartView x:Name="chartView"/>
<Button Content="Copy To Clipboard" 
        Command="{Binding ElementName=chartView, 
                          Path=CopyToClipboardCommand}"/>
```

I tried this and a bunch of variations, but no luck. Is there any way to do this?

Edit:

I tried doing this with a Dependency Property. Here is the TraceChartView code behind:

```
private static readonly DependencyProperty CopyToClipboardCommandProperty =   
    DependencyProperty.Register("CopyToClipboardCommand",
                                typeof(ICommand),
                                typeof(TraceChartView),
                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnSomePropertyChanged));

private static void OnSomePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, 
                                          DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // never called
}

public ICommand CopyToClipboardCommand
{
    set
    {
        this.SetValue(CopyToClipboardCommandProperty, value);
    }
    get
    {
        return (ICommand)this.GetValue(CopyToClipboardCommandProperty);
    }
}
```

I tried binding like this:

```
<local:TraceChartView x:Name="chartView"/>
<Button Content="Copy To Clipboard" 
        Command="{Binding ElementName=chartView, 
                          Path=CopyToClipboardCommand}"/>
```

This doesn't produce any console errors, but my callback is never called.

Comment: I would use an attached dependency property.

Comment: if you own `TraceChartView` it doesn't need to be an attached dependency property, it can be a `DependencyProperty` on the `TraceChartView` class itself.

Comment: I've you've tried a bunch of variations, show some, and any binding errors you got from the console.  because you're right, you *should* be able to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with my code is that I created a dependency property, but I never set the property to anything.  When I did this in the constructor, it worked:

```
public TraceChartView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    CopyToClipboardCommand = new RelayCommand(DoCopyToClipboard);
}
```

For my implementation, I don't really need a dependency property, and the whole thing can be implemented with a single line in the code behind:

```
public RelayCommand CopyToClipboardCommand { get { return new RelayCommand(DoCopyToClipboard); } }
```

with this xaml:

```
<local:TraceChartView x:Name="chartView"/>
<Button Content="Copy To Clipboard" 
    Command="{Binding ElementName=chartView, 
                      Path=CopyToClipboardCommand}"/>
```

I hope that this will help some other WPF beginner.